# Several Questions regarding software on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, performance, adobe, playonlinux

So, i recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 but i have problems setting up my microphone, i got a creative sound-card and i already tried ALSA.
Second i need to have adobe cs 5.5 installed for studying but wine doesn't work with installing it via cdrom, i heard there is a workaround the installer but i cant seem to find any ;( 
and at last i am playing league of legends and D3 , i got both to work with playonlinux but the performance seems pretty bad even tho i have a good system with amd 6xcpu 2gb gpu etc, I'm running gnome classic ui on 2 screens , I'm not sure maybe you can get me some hints on increasing performance , i tried several stuff i found on the interwebz but doesn't work so well.

Comment: One Question per one post only please.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're missing some drivers. Sound and Graphics. You probably have to do additional research on your options specific to your cards if the drivers Ubuntu suggested on installation aren't cutting it.

Using Wine is a pain I find. If you have to, then I'd try torrenting a clean copy of the Creative Suite .iso from piratebay and installing from that, and then just entering your serial. However, maybe that won't work either. Have you considered using GIMP for your photoshop needs? I find it literally does everything photoshop does and it's free! Very impressive software to be provided to the masses.

Comment: No actually i have to use cs 5.5 because i have a student and teacher edition there with teaching content aiming for adobe products ;/ I installed propietary fglxr thingy drivers already for graphics, for sound i dont really know but everything is working fine there except the microphone.

Comment: Amazing! That's good news! The microphone shouldn't be too hard to fix! As for cs 5.5, I understand you can't use alternatives, but besides fiddling with Wine, I have no idea. Though it looks like bad news: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23499. I'd have to recommend sticking to Windows or Mac since this software is not designed for Ubuntu. I'd make a question addressing running Creative Suite on Ubuntu, and maybe someone has figured it out.

Comment: Thank you for answering so far, yeah i thought about getting Windows again but i cant install it dualboot because my usb keyboard only boots in the OS and even the ps/2 port wont work, but i didnt wanted to switch complete, so i guess i have to figure out how to vmware.                                                         For sound: yeah ofcourse thats amazing the sound works, but the actual problem since beginning was the microphone thats why i even asked here ;D sound was working from beginning^^ thats the real problem ;/